# The minimal primes of $k[x,y]/\langle xy,x^3-x^2\rangle$

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

> Given the following primary decomposition in $k[x,y]$, $k$ field:
>
> $$I=\langle xy,x^3-x^2\rangle=\langle x\rangle \cap \langle x-1,y\rangle \cap \langle x^2,y\rangle,$$
>
> I want to compute the minimal primes of $k[x,y]/I$.

The associated primes are:

- $\sqrt{\langle x \rangle}=\langle x \rangle$ (prime);
- $\sqrt{\langle x-1,y \rangle}=\langle x-1,y \rangle$ (maximal).
- $\sqrt{\langle x^2,y \rangle}=\langle x,y \rangle$, because of the inclusion $\supseteq$ is obvious and $\langle x,y\rangle$  is maximal.

  So, the minimal primes of $k[x,y]/I$ are given by $\langle x-1,y \rangle/I$ and $\langle x\rangle/I$.

Once I was beginner and the corectness of the answer is very important to me, I'd like to know if I am correct.

Many thanks in advance!